# Authenticating users via LDAP with Shiro

Tags: java, grails, groovy, ldap, shiro

Total newbie to java/groovy/grails/shiro/you-name-it, so bear with me. I have exhausted tutorials and all the "Shiro LDAP" searches available and still cannot get my project working.

I am running all of this on GGTS with jdk1.7.0_80, Grails 2.3.0, and Shiro 1.2.1.

I have a working project and have successfully ran quick-start-shiro,which built the domains ShiroRole and ShiroUser, the controller authController, the view login.gsp, and the relam ShiroDbRealm. I created a faux user in BootStrap with

```
def user = new ShiroUser(username: "user123", passwordHash: new Sha256Hash("password").toHex())
user.addToPermissions("*:*")
user.save()
```

and can successfully log into my homepage, and for all intents and purposes, that is as far as I have gotten. I cannot find a top-down tutorial of how to now log in with my username and password (authenticated through a LDAP server that I have available). From what I understand, I need to create a shiro.ini file and include something along the lines of

```
[main]
ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
ldapRealm.url = ldap://MYURLHERE/
```

However I don't even know where to put this shiro.ini file. I've seen /src/main/resources, but there is no such directory. Do I manually create this or is it some script creation?

The next step seems to be creating the SecurityManager which reads the shiro.ini somehow with code along the lines of

```
Factory<org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("actived.ini");

// Setting up the SecurityManager...
org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

However this always appears in some Java file in tutorials, but my project is a Groovy project inside of GGTS. Do I need to create a Java file and put it in src/java or something like that?

I've recently found that I may need a ShiroLdapRealm file (similar to ShiroDbRealm) with information like

```
def appConfig = grailsApplication.config
def ldapUrls = appConfig.ldap.server.url ?: [ "ldap://MYURLHERE/" ]
def searchBase = appConfig.ldap.search.base ?: ""
def searchUser = appConfig.ldap.search.user ?: ""
def searchPass = appConfig.ldap.search.pass ?: ""
def usernameAttribute = appConfig.ldap.username.attribute ?: "uid"
def skipAuthc = appConfig.ldap.skip.authentication ?: false
def skipCredChk = appConfig.ldap.skip.credentialsCheck ?: false
def allowEmptyPass = appConfig.ldap.allowEmptyPasswords != [:] ? appConfig.ldap.allowEmptyPasswords : true
```

and the corresponding info in Config along the lines of

```
ldap.server.url = ["ldap://MYRULHERE/"]
ldap.search.base = 'dc=COMPANYNAME,dc=com'
ldap.search.user = ''       // if empty or null --> anonymous user lookup
ldap.search.pass = 'password'                // only used with     non-anonymous lookup
ldap.username.attribute = 'AccountName'
ldap.referral = "follow"
ldap.skip.credentialsCheck = false
ldap.allowEmptyPasswords = false
ldap.skip.authentication = false
```

But putting all these pieces together hasn't gotten me anywhere! Am I at least on the right track? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For `/src/main/resources` it will automatically created for you if you used maven for your project. Moreover, you can also create that directory manually.